# Finding unique pairs in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming

Given this input `[3,1,2]` I want to have this output `[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 3 ] ]`

Its the unique pairs (`[1,2] == [2,1]`)

Currently I've made that

```
const arr = [3,1,2];
const pairBuilder = (left, index, collection) =>
  collection.slice(index).map(right => [left, right]);

const pairs = arr.sort().flatMap(pairBuilder);
console.log(pairs)
```

This code is functional, but I wonder if there is not a better way (in terms of performances) to achieve this ? I've though of using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11) to improve sorting / mapping (with `chain`), but my question is more about algorithm improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) with a [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and slice the array for getting only unique pairs.

```js
function* getPairs(array, left) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (left) yield [left, array[i]];
        else yield* getPairs(array.slice(i), array[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

var array = [1, 2, 3];

console.log([...getPairs(array)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A classic approach.

```js
function getPairs(array) {
    var i, j, result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
            result.push([array[i], array[j]]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(getPairs(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: nice ! Did not though about using a generator

Comment: You really should recurse here and use an optional `left` parameter. Just nest two loops!

Comment: @Bergi, why has this answer so much attention? i can add another solution.

Comment: @NinaScholz What do you mean by "so much attention"? I just came across it on the min page, and found that the code should be improved.

Answer (score -1):

This is a naive and slow approach. 
But i beleive it is faster than accepted answer and answer in the question.
It generates less new objects overhead and requires less memory.
Naive algorithm doesn't use recursion. so does not face recursion limit (50 by default)
Also i beleive it's still readable and easy to understand

```js
        const inp = [3, 1,2];

        function genPair(inp) {
            const length = inp.length;
            const sorted = inp.sort();
            const result = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                for (let j = i; j < length; j++) {
                    result.push([sorted[i], sorted[j]]);
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
        const r = genPair(inp);
        console.log(r);
```

link to js perf
https://jsperf.com/find-dups/1
Accepted answer in IE11 60% slower and in Chrome 10% slower